# using php form to input data into user's mysql record

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to use a php form to take the logged in user's username id and their input and add that input into a column under their user data in mysql...

So far, I did a phpfusion custom page that has the following code that creates a form but I believe it is lacking the correct code to set the username variable in order to look up the user id in the input file.

```
<p>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Set/Change MineCraft Password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
        <tr>
          <td>MineCraft Password</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="MC password" size="20">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" 
          name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<?php
$userdata['user_name']="username"
?>
</p>
```

Then the input file looks a litte bit like the following:

```
<?
//the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form
//input.php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");//database connection
mysql_select_db("database");

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO data_employees
        (user_name, user_mcpass)
        VALUES
        ('$user_name',
        '$MC password')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
?>
```

Currently it has not been able to input anything into the mysql but returns the success message.

Any help?!?!

Comment: Two things, one -> where are you assigning the `$user_name` and `$MC password` and two -> `$MC password` is an invalid variable.

Answer (score 0):

Where is `$user_name` and `$MC password`?

First change this :

`<td><input type="text" name="MC password" size="20">`

to

`<td><input type="text" name="MC_password" size="20">`

Then try your query.

Comment: But where are they translating $_POST['MC_password'] to $MC_password?

Answer (score 0):

Why you have put a space between `$MC password` in sql query. if it is a variable then remove this space.

Also You are vulnerable from SQL injection. Use **mysqli_query()** method for sql query instead of **mysql_query** .

Answer (score 0):

You have errors in both your form and in your processing. You should also switch your `mysql` to `PDO` or `mysqli`

```
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Set/Change MineCraft Password</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>
        <form method="post" action="input.php">
        <tr>
          <td>MineCraft Password</td>
          <td><input type="text" name="password" size="20"></td>
          <td><input type="text" name="username" size="20"></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td></td>
          <td align="right"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit"></td>
        </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<?
//the example of inserting data with variable from HTML form
//input.php
mysql_connect("localhost","root","admin");//database connection
mysql_select_db("database");

$username = htmlentities($_POST['username'],ENT_QUOTES);
$username = htmlentities($_POST['password'],ENT_QUOTES);

//inserting data order
$order = "INSERT INTO data_employees
        (user_name, user_mcpass)
        VALUES
        ('$username',
        '$password')";

//declare in the order variable
$result = mysql_query($order);  //order executes
if($result){
    echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
} else{
    echo("<br>Input data is fail");
}
?>
```

Comment: You should explain the errors and then provide an answer with non-deprecated code, something like `MySQLi` or even better, `PDO`.

Comment: I provided his code back in a fashion that will work with a suggestion to switch to newer db methods. If that is important, he'll switch...or one day it will stop working...

Comment: See the problem is most people use this site by going to a search engine and searching for an answer. They won't see your comment about the MySQLi or PDO and will see the old bad code. Just a suggestion. He needs to learn something up to date regardless.

Comment: True dat...he does need to use a newer DB architecture.

Answer (score 0):

You need to post the variables and retrieve them in PHP when the user submits the form. You typically do that with something like this:

```
if (isset($_POST['username'])) {
    // Put them in a local variable
    $uname = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['username']); // Sanitize the variable
    $pass = mysqli_real_escape_string($link, $_POST['MC_Password']); // Sanitize the variable

    $order = "INSERT INTO data_employees
    (user_name, user_mcpass)
    VALUES
    ('$uname',
    '$pass')";

     $result = mysqli_query($link, $order);  //order executes 
     if($result){
         echo("<br>Input data is succeed");
     } else{
         echo("<br>Input data is fail");
     }
}
```

By the way, "MC Password" won't work for the name of your HTML password input field (can't have spaces), so I would change it to something like "MC_Password," which is what I used in my code above.

Hope it helps!